# Change uint_8 to x times binary 1 MSB

Tags: c++, hardware

I'm writing a Max72xx library for my school project and I have found a way to set columns using the registers that comes with the datasheet. Now, I also found a way to set their height. So I have created a function with two parameters: `row`, which basically sends the x-axis to the chip, and height which sets the y-axis. 
 
What I did in this code is basically the following:

- The user sets an x-axis between 1 and 8 (parameter `const uint8_t& row`)
- The user sets an y-axis between 1 and 8 (parameter `uint8_t height`)

I wanted to achieve the following:

- If the `height` is set to three: the following bit pattern should be created: `1110 000`. Or, if the user uses 8, I want the function to create `1111 1111`. Or if the user sets 5 as y-axis I want the fucntin to create a bit pattern of `1111 1000`, etcetera.

The code I have provided is the following (this piece of code is within the function setColumn):

```
if (height >= 1 && height <= 8) { // if the height is between the matrix range
    uint8_t pattern = 0x00; // create a pattern to send to the chip
    uint8_t counter = 0; // counter for counting the zeros to shift left later on

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < height - 1; i++) { // this loop is repeated height amount of times
        pattern |= 0x01; // create 1s in the pattern
        pattern <<= 0x01; // shift it 1 to the left
    }
    pattern |= 0x01; // OR the LSB bit of the pattern

    for (uint8_t i = 7; i > 0; i--) { // count the leading 0 bits to shift them to the MSB position
        if (!(pattern >> i) & 1)
            counter++;
        else break;
    }
    pattern <<= counter;
```

The MSB is the lowest pixel on the display, the LSB the highest pixel.
Now this code works as I described earlier, but I think there is an easier and more efficient way to work this out. I'd like to know some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use this:

```
uint8_t pattern = (0xff00u >> height);
```

Or this:

```
uint8_t pattern = (0xffu << (8 - height));
```

Don't be afraid of overflows during bit shifting as long as the arguments are *unsigned*, the behavior is [well-defined](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.shift).

Comment: What does the U stand for?

Comment: The suffix `u` means unsigned.

Answer (score 4):

Only 8 patterns? I would just define a `const` array:

````
```
static const uint8_t patterns[] = {
  0x10000000,
  0x11000000,
  0x11100000,
  0x11110000,
  0x11111000,
  0x11111100,
  0x11111110,
  0x11111111,
};

if (height >= 1 && height <=8)
  return patterns[height - 1];

// raise an exception or so
````

Comment: Yes only 8 patterns. The chip has 8x8 pixels so it's not necessairy to create an uint16_t or more since I'm not daisy chaining the chips. Your answer however is way more easier than I expected, thank you.